# How to join an existing activity playing media in chrome app

Tags: google-cast

So assuming you've already launched media on the receiver from an iOS/Android/Web app, how can another web app join this activity and control the media? I noticed that the cast API has a 'JOIN_ACTIVITY' in it, but there's nothing that currently uses it. Nor do you know the activity's ID to join it..

This is similar to [How to check if a ChromeCast Session is already in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219184/how-to-check-if-a-chromecast-session-is-already-in-progress) however, this answer does not help to connect to an existing application

However, using the javascript API, even if you know your app is running I can't find a way to connect to it without re-launching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get some answers from the Google engineering team:

> We allow clients to reconnect to the same session if they are launched
>   from the same origin (i.e. http://www.somedomain.com:80/).  We don't
>   have the support in the V1 protocol stack to implement this across
>   multiple browsers.  We can hard code something for V1 like mapping
>   origins to app ids, but it will still be some eng effort to add the
>   API support as well.

In short, the functionality from Android and iOS is currently missing from the Chrome SDK... hope it comes out soon.

**EDIT**: To update this, now that the official public SDK has been released, this is now supported!

Comment: I know it's been years but I'm running into this same problem and can't figure out how to connect to an existing session. Any chance you could elaborate a little on that last EDIT? A link or something would probably suffice :)